# Deployed Website not working in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-6, web-hosting

I locally hosted my asp.net (razor) application on my machine. The website is hosted but giving some errors. I have fixed some of them but now when i hit url the website open in directory browser mode

```
  localhost - /mytls/

[To Parent Directory]

 3/20/2015 11:43 AM        <dir> bin
 3/20/2015 11:43 AM        <dir> Content
 3/20/2015 11:43 AM        <dir> EmailTemplates
 3/19/2015  4:25 PM          115 Global.asax
 3/19/2015  4:25 PM         2587 logging.config
 3/19/2015  4:25 PM         2062 packages.config
 3/20/2015 11:43 AM        <dir> Scripts
 3/20/2015 11:43 AM        <dir> Views
 3/20/2015 12:24 PM         6879 Web.config
```

Comment: Did you check the application pool for your website on IIS manager? it should be `Managed Pipeline mode: integrated` and `.Net CLR Version: <select the version you want>`

Comment: Actually the mvc 4 is not installed now its working correctly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happen if you disable direcotry browsing?
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(v=ws.10).aspx

And check your default start page.
If you use MVC it can be in the RouterConfig.cs

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            // default route here 
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new[] { "MyApplication.Web.Controllers" }
        );
    }
```

Comment: When i disable browsing following error occurs---->A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Comment: What is your Controller name? and the View's name? Should be something like: new { controller = "Account", action = "login", id = UrlParameter.Optional } if you use standard template login

Comment: i have recovered the issue that for helping. the asp.net was not installed at my machine.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this issue is very simple. I just **install asp.net** *(version in which you develop your website)* on my machine. Restart IIS server.
The website start working.